# How to identify if a user clicked on an anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have an anchor link:

```
<a name="mylink" class="myclass"></a>
```

I send a link to an e-mail of my user with a link:

http://preloaders.net/en/social_bookmarks/#mylink

How do I identify if the link has been clicked with jQuery/Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with pure JavaScript:

```
if (window.location.hash == '#mylink') ...
```

Comment: I did not know this was possible.  Cool question; useful answer. +1 for all :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Cito! Just before refreshed this page found the answer too, by exploding the full url by "#" :) But your solution is "cleaner" than mine :). Thanks